# Using @link in a @return description truncates text

Tags: doxygen

I've hit a snag with Doxygen (v1.8.16) and am hoping someone can help. The function I'm documenting returns an enum that's described elsewhere, so I want to link to it in the generated documentation. All is fine and dandy on that front.

```
<myheader.h>
/* ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ MyCoolFunction() ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ */
/**
 * @brief This function does lots of cool stuff. You should check it out.
 *
 * Here's another line of text describing what a great function this is.
 *
 * @since 2.1.1
 *
 * @return
 * The @link THE_RESULT @endlink enumeration.
 * <TABLE>
 * <TR><TH>Result</TH><TH>Description</TH></TR>
 * <TR><TD>@link SUCCESS @endlink</TD><TD>The method ran perfectly.</TD></TR>
 * <TR><TD>@link ERROR1 @endlink</TD><TD>The method didn't run so well.</TD></TR>
 * <TR><TD>@link ERROR2 @endlink</TD><TD>The method utterly failed.</TD></TR>
 * </TABLE>
 *
 * @see MyOtherFunction
 * @ingroup These_Methods
 */
THE_METHOD THE_RESULT MyCoolFunction();
```

And here's an example of calling my function:

```
<mylittleapp.cpp>

/**

 * @file mylittleapp.cpp
 * @brief Here's an example of how to use MyCoolFunction.
 */
void Example()
{
    if (MyCoolFunction() == SUCCESS)
    {
        // Now we get to do more cool stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Uh oh!
    }
}
```

The problem is for the SDK user when they want the context documentation popping up about how to use the function in their code. When I mouse-over MyCoolFunction in mylittleapp.cpp, this is what I see when the @link is in the @return.

[image]

Removing the @link...@endlink in the @return line fixes that problem, but then there's no link to my THE_RESULT enum in the generated documentation. How can I get the full return statement to show up in the context pop-up and also include a link in the generated doc?

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.16 is a bit older ((August 8, 2019), the current version is 1.9.4 The problem you signal probably is not a doxygen problem (as you imply in the first paragraph of your question), so as you say it must be a SDK problem. Question is which SDK?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The SDK is the one I'm documenting. :)  I'll check with Engineering to see if they can upgrade to a newer version. Meanwhile, maybe I'll use \see to get the link into the doc and leave it unlinked in the \return.

Comment: Your solution and the original problem is still unclear to me, probably due to missing information. Btw. which output format are you using (I assumed HTML but this looks different from the results you presented.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Yes, we output to HTML. We won't be upgrading the version of Doxygen immediately, so for the time being, we'll have to stick with the \refs in the \briefs for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `@link ... @endlink` isn't correct for internal links. Changing them to `@ref`s fixes both problems.